# user input string with arraylist

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How do I Compare user input string to array list then remove user string letters from the arraylist here's my code:

I want to get user input as string e.g Apple then I want to remove the letters "a" "p" "l" "e" from the arraylist.

```
public static void playgame() {

    ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>(
    Arrays.asList("a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z"));

        while(!obj.isEmpty()) {

            System.out.println(name1 + " enter your word:");
            String word1 = reader.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println("Enter (y) yes if both players agree on the word and (n) no word is incorrect");
            String y = reader.next();

            String yes = "y";
            String no = "n";

            if(y.equals(yes)) {

                countScore1++;
                char[] wordToString = word1.toCharArray();

                System.out.println(wordToString.length);

                for(int i=0;i<wordToString.length;i++) {

                    String output=Character.toString(wordToString[i]);

                    System.out.println(output);

                        if(obj.contains(output)){
                            obj.remove(output);
                        }   
                }
                System.out.println("Alphabet letters left:" + obj);
                System.out.println("Correct word #######");
            }
```

Comment: Your list contains a single element with the whole alphabet. You need to put the individual letters in double quotes, e.g. `"a", "b"` etc

Comment: Also, you don't need to check `contains` before `remove`: calling `remove` for an element that isn't present won't do anything, so it is safe.

Comment: Thanks let me try that, it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

See Andy Turner's message about single string. In practice, replace

```
ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>(
Arrays.asList("a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z"));
```

for example with this

```
List<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    obj.add(String.valueOf(c));
}
```

However, I would use HashSet instead of ArrayList. I guess HashSet has faster lookup algorithm when looking for the item to remove.

```
Set<String> obj = new HashSet<String>(); 
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    obj.add(String.valueOf(c));
}
```